# Elasticsearch in php doesn't recognize dash

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm working on a project and try to make a search with elasticsearch but my field can contain dash and when I search with it I can't find the result I'm looking for, so I tried to change the mapping but the index doesn't work at all. I don't have any error message but I can't find what I indexed even using a different field. So what I did was :

```
 $params = [
'index' => 'arc',
'type' => 'purchase',
'id' => $purchase['id'],
'body' => $purchase
];
```

It worked great with that except for the field with the dash. My `$purchase` looks like that :

```
 array:34 [
    "id" => 163160
    "distant" => "MOR-938BBM28147090"
[...]
]
```

so when I search for "MOR" I find the result but when I do "MOR-" nothing. I tried to change the mapping by doing that :

```
 $params = [
        'index' => 'arc',
        'type' => 'purchase',
        'id' => $purchase['id'],
        'body' => [
            'mappings' => [
                '_default_' => [
                    'properties' => [
                        'distant' => [
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            $purchase
        ]
    ];
```

But with that even if I try to search "163160" I can't find any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) could be the right solution in this case. It takes into account only whitespaces while breaking text into tokens, and characters like "-" or "_" are still treated as a part of a term.

But if you need to do a partial matching, for example with `"MOR-"` token, then it requires a bit more complicated mapping.

As I don't know php, I'll be using Elasticsearch syntax. First, create a proper mapping:

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:9200/arc
{
    "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 18,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "mappings": {
        "purchase": {
            "properties": {
                "distant": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use [EdgeNGram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer here. When you index a document with `MOR-938BBM28147090` in `distant` field, it will create following tokens:

```
[MOR, MOR-, MOR-9, MOR-93, MOR-938, MOR-938B, MOR-938BB, ...]
```

The core point here is `punctuation` character class in `token_chars` list, that tells elasticsearch, that dash character (and some others like ! or ") should be included in a token and not treated as a "split char".

Now when I index the document:

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:9200/arc/purchase/163160
{
    "distant": "MOR-938BBM28147090"
}
```

and run a term search query:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/arc/purchase/_search
{
    "query": {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : {
          "term" : {
             "distant": "MOR-93"
           }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I get in response:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.6337049,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "arc",
            "_type": "purchase",
            "_id": "163160",
            "_score": 0.6337049,
            "_source": {
                "distant": "MOR-938BBM28147090"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Same as before, I can't find my purchase even using the "id" param

Comment: Oh right, I missed that you need partial matching. Please check my updated answer.